My boot partition is showing /boot is 83% on Ubuntu Server, How can free this?
My boot partition is showing /boot is 83% on Ubuntu Server, How can I free this? Is it safe to execute sudo apt-get clean

83 percent of what? Also what is the version of Ubuntu?

Does this answer your question? How do I free up more space in /boot?

This is what I see
Filesystem            1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                    809216     1628    807588   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01 121147748 78745852  37379052  68% /
tmpfs                   4046060        4   4046056   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda1                498900   383064     79140  83% /boot
tmpfs                    809212        8    809204   1% /run/user/0
